# Transform a text having multiple uppercase words into a text having one uppercase and other lowercase words

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I transform a string like:

```
let a = "ProductionTest"
```

to a string like:

```
Production test
```

I know how to detect the upper case letters with regex like:

```
a.match(/[A-Z]/g)
```

but cannot understand, how could I use this to transform the text as given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

search for the `[A-Z]` characters, then use `.replace()` with a callback function to add a space and convert the matched character to lower case.

```js
let a = "ProductionTest";

let res = a[0] + a.slice(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => " " + m.toLowerCase());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
let a = "ProductionTest"
let b = a.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g).join(' ').toLowerCase()
let c = b.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + b.slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for you

```
'ProductionTest'.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g).reduce((cur, n)=> cur + ' ' + n.toLowerCase());
```